# Did the US provide its own estimates of hunger in Gaza during the 2023 war?

Tags: united-states, united-nations, 2023-israel-hamas-war, gaza, food

During the Tigray war, the US apparently provided its own estimates of hunger in the region, [e.g.](https://apnews.com/article/ethiopia-africa-famine-262c0faa72a9eb20fd0151c5ba7a7e91)

> June 26, 2021
>
> The United States estimates that up to 900,000 people in Ethiopia’s Tigray region now face famine conditions amid a deadly conflict, even as the prime minister says there is “no hunger” there.

It's not too clear to me what scale the US uses for that, but the numbers were a bit higher than those provided by the  Integrated Food Security Phase Classification using their "IPC Phase 5" (Catastrophe) assessment, which [stood](https://www.ipcinfo.org/ipc-country-analysis/details-map/fi/c/1154897/?iso3=ETH) at around 350,000 at that point (May - June 2021), but lower than the same estimates for [the broader] IPC Phase 4 (Emergency) during the same time frame, which were about 2 million (not including those in Phase 5).

So, I'm curious: **did the US make its own estimates of hunger in Gaza during the current war** there, and do those estimates differ substantially from [those of the IPC](https://www.ipcinfo.org/ipc-country-analysis/details-map/en/c/1156749/?iso3=PSE) (which reported 377,800 in Phase 5 and 939,000 in Phase 4 in Gaza for the period of 24 November to 7 December 2023)?